# Replacing x-values in tikz coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

With the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[colormap/blackwhite,legend style ={ at={(1.03,1)}, 
    anchor=north west, draw=black, 
    fill=white,align=left},
cycle list name=black white,
smooth]
\addplot coordinates{(1,0.895975056689342) (2,0.88858024691358) (3,0.845842956120092) (4,0.939493433395872) (5,0.876114081996435) (6,0.855309218203034) (7,0.85309649543927) (8,0.894003868471954) (9,0.857021996615905) (10,0.842038753159225) (11,0.89045719545873) (12,0.839759462327556) (13,0.794553464156988) (14,0.800123762376238)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I can plot e.g. an experimental curve. I would like to replace x-values with couples like, e.g. (5,95) instead 1, (6,94) instead 2 and so on. Like this:

[image]

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you mean, could you try to clarify?

Comment: Possibly `symbolic x coordinates` is what you need.

Comment: I  updated the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naive attempt with `symbolic x coords` didn't work, but you can do this by specifying the `xtick` and `xticklabels` manually.  `xtick` can take a list of numbers, something like `{1,...,5}` which gives integers from 1 to 5, or the keyword `data` (i.e. `xtick=data`) which will place a tick for each datapoint in the *first* `\addplot`.

`xticklabels` takes a comma separated list of text to use for the ticklabels. In your case you need to wrap each ticklabel in `{}`, because there is a comma in them. See a complete example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  colormap/blackwhite,
  legend style = {
    at={(1.03,1)}, 
    anchor=north west,
    align=left
  },
  cycle list name=black white,
  smooth,
  xtick={1,5,9},
  xticklabels={{(1,3.13)},{(2,42)},{(3,1.618)}}
  ]

\addplot coordinates{(1,0.895975056689342) (2,0.88858024691358) (3,0.845842956120092) (4,0.939493433395872) (5,0.876114081996435) (6,0.855309218203034) (7,0.85309649543927) (8,0.894003868471954) (9,0.857021996615905) (10,0.842038753159225) (11,0.89045719545873) (12,0.839759462327556) (13,0.794553464156988) (14,0.800123762376238)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [xtick=data] will do some of the work, but you will still need manual xticklalels.